# Calling setDefaultValue() on a custom Preference class does not set the default value. Why?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preference, listpreference

I'm extending `PreferenceActivity` for my settings screen. In this preference activity i have a couple of preferences one of which is custom made. The problem is as follows:

in this custom preference (which extends from `ListPreference`) i want to be able to set the default value, so i override the `setDefaultValue()` method. In this method i do some parsing so it'll take the correct value. When i'm trying to read this value with the `getValue()` function it just returns `null`.

So i figured, what happens when i just put some hardcoded value in there (you know, maybe i did something wrong, wouldn't be the first time). Well, i still get `null` back.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Setting the defaultValue in the xml file isn't really an option because the values aren't known until i retrieve them.

I made a workaround:

- When app is started for the first time: get data
- Set the values in the preference.

This way i set the default preference when i'm collection the data

Comment: Are you calling setDefaultValue() before you call getValue()? I set my default preferences in a preferences.xml file which is read before my preference view is created - how do you set your defaults?

Comment: yes i do, but in code. The problem is that i don't know the default value until the app is first started. So i try to set it the first time the user opens the preferenceactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDefaultValue` doesn't work the way you think it does. Look at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/preference/Preference.java#Preference) of `Preference.java` and you'll the logic behind it all.

The preferred way to set a default is to specify the `android:defaultValue` attribute in the `preferences.xml` file of your app.

Comment: Well i can't really because the entries aren't static. The only (dirty) workaround i see is just set a flag in the preference that i set when setting the default value and just use setValue().

Answer (score 5):

I finally found [the solution](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2012-07/msg03374.html) (somewhere besides StackOverflow, for once).

When you create a custom Preference class,

1. You need to implement `onSetInitialValue` as [XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I -](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161752/404597) pointed out
2. You **also** need to implement [`onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index)`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#CustomDefault)

For example, if the custom preference is saved as an int,

```
@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue) {
    setValue(restore ? getPersistedInt(FALLBACK_DEFAULT_VALUE) : (Integer) defaultValue);
}
@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
   return a.getInteger(index, FALLBACK_DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Now `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues()` **finally** loads the `android:defaultValue` for the custom preferences too. Still no fix for nulls and false, but there are workarounds for those posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call `getValue()` after calling `setDefaultValue()` to retrieve a default value the first time your PreferenceActivity opens, you need to override `onSetInitialValue()` in your Preference subclass. Otherwise, the default value will not be set when you call `getValue()` and it will return a `null` (as you experienced).

For example, if your default value is an integer, your `onSetInitialValue()` might look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue)
{
    setValue(restore ? getPersistedInt(DEFAULT_VALUE) : (Integer) defaultValue);
}
```

`DEFAULT_VALUE` is just a private constant inside the Preference to be used in case the persisted int cannot be retrieved. `setValue()` is the public setter to complement your `getValue()` public getter, and should look something like this:

```
public int getValue()
{
    return mValue;
}

public void setValue(int value)
{
    if (value != mValue)
    {
        mValue = value;
        persistInt(value);
    }
}
```

For more information about `onSetInitialValue()`, refer to the API documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#onSetInitialValue%28boolean,%20java.lang.Object%29).

It's also a good idea to look at the source code of the Preference class ([here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java)) to understand why `onSetInitialValue()` needs to be implemented. In particular, have a look at `setDefaultValue()`, and then look at `dispatchSetInitialValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

I converted preferences `.xml` to code. All `setDefaultValue`s works well there.

```
val screen = preferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(context)

val editText = EditTextPreference(context).apply {
         setIcon(R.drawable.lobat_cloud)
         key = "key"
         title = "MyPreferences"
         ...

         setDefaultValue("My Default Value")
      }

screen.addPreference(editText)

// add other preferences

preferenceScreen = screen
```

[more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/programmatic-hierarchy)

P.S: I found this way more smaller and clear than customizing all preferences or other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend preference and set the default value during constructing like this:

```
package com.example.package.preference;

public class CustomPreference extends ListPreference{

public CustomPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Object anyDefaultValueFromCode = ...
    setDefaultValue(anyDefaultValueFromCode );
}
}
```

then you can use it from XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="alarm_prefs_screen"
android:title="@string/set_alarm" >

<com.example.package.preference.CustomPreference
    android:key="custom_preference"
    android:title="@string/any_title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and worked for me:

```
class DefaultValueEditTextPreference : androidx.preference.EditTextPreference {
    @Suppress("unused")
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    @Suppress("unused")
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    @Suppress("unused")
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    @Suppress("unused")
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)

    init {
        text = ... //the default, dynamic text that you want to have
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this works too at anytime.

```
 Preference aaa = (Preference) findPreference("xxx");
 aaa.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

              public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                    // For edit text preference
                    ((EditTextPreference)preference).getEditText().setText("foobar");


                    // for list preference
                    (ListPreference)preference).setValue("foobar");

                    // etc ...

            return true;
              }
 });
```

This code will detect when the dialog is about to launch and populate the EditText or List in the dialog with your default value.

Comment: This doesn't work. The preference value is set but, at least for a `ListPreference`, the list is not populate.